# Multi-subclass Data Structure for Train/test/Validation Split

Tags: python, tensorflow, multiclass-classification, train-test-split

I have a dataset of Apple, Pineapple and Strawberry images. In this dataset, there are mature/immature/partially mature ripe images of these fruits. The data was previously separated as train/test/validation. How can I split this data for CNN using sklearn/train_test_split? I am sharing the folder structure with you.
[Dataset Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7lF6.jpg)

In previous studies, classes were available under the train folder. I was doing my project without any problems. However, in this dataset, there is a class within a class in the train folder. So I don't know what to do. I tried to do it using Python but it didn't work.

Comment: Look into multi-label classification.

Comment: "I tried to do it using Python but it didn't work." We don't know what didn't work unless you show us very specifically. Please [post your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and we can help.